# jQuery on Click everything inside element

Tags: jquery

When I click anything on the page, other than `.card` I want my function to fire. It works perfectly, however, if I have a `<h2>hello</h2>` inside my `.card` and I click on that, it also fires.

How do I get my jQuery to not fire if all/any elements inside `.card` are clicked, including `.card`?

Here is my code:

```
$('body').click(function(evt){    
   if(!$(evt.target).is('.card')) {
      $('.card').removeClass('active');
      $('.offer2').addClass('active');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Just do an extra check for closest `.card`. If there isn't a parent card then you know you didn;t click on the card

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect a click outside an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the clicked item is inside of card or not

`$(evt.target).closest(".card").length == 0` checks if there is a parent card, if the length is 0 then you know you did not click inside of a card

```js
$('body').click(function(evt){    
   if($(evt.target).closest(".card").length == 0) {
      console.log("hi");
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <h2>not hi</h2>
  not hi
</div>

<h1>hi</h1>
```

Alternatively you could also do something like this, negate the click for `.card`, by returning false, anything inside of card also gets trapped

```js
$('body').click(function(evt) {
  console.log("hi");
});

$('.card').click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <h2>not hi</h2>
</div>

<h1>hi</h1>
```

Comment: ...or just follow the advice in the proposed duplicate's answers :).

Comment: ` if(!$(evt.target).is('.card') && $(evt.target).closest(".card").length == 0) {` makes little sense. Just the length check is fine.

Comment: you are right, removed. closest checks itself as well

Answer (score 0):

When cliked on an element an event object passed to the function like `function(evt)` The event `evt` has a property `target` which contain the current element and its parents element html. So when a click event fired, we need to check for the closest element which have a specific class/ID like `card`. If the target property have not any closest element with class card then it means we clicked outside the card element.

```
   $('body').on('click', function(evt){    
      if($(evt.target).closest('.card').length<=0){
//Write your code here. 
console.log('Clicked out side Card');

    }
     });
```

Comment: @devHensh this will work for you. try this easy solution.